# Layout rerendering while changing the route in next js 14 approuter concept

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes

I am new to next js and I wish create a navbar and shared it between components using the approuter concept. I am using next js version "14.0.2". I have mentioned my folder structre below in the image [image]
The problem is that whenever I navigate to a new route the layout.js is rerendering how to control the rerendering in this secnario.This is my layout.js code [image]
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: How do you know it's re-rendering?

Comment: I can visually see the difference while changing routes. However after mentioning a static height the issue is fixed

Answer (score 0):

Its fixed after defining a static height for the navbar section. Don't know whether it is a right solution, but it works fine now